# Facebook Conversion API doesn't work properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, server-side

Does anyone know why Test Events in FB Business manager doesn't work properly? I ran FB Conversion API, and I can see data is being sent properly but every time I want to use Test events for QA purposes, I can't see some of the events coming from the Server. For example for PageView event it works just fine but if I change the event name to Contact it looks like below:
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help